# Do I lose experience by completing another brew without assigning the last level up?

Tags: fiz

Each of my employees can level up individually at the end of a brew;

[image]

I have been queuing up multiple brews and selling them one after another while skipping this screen. Do I lose experience by completing another brew without assigning the last level up? Do employees continue to gain experience while waiting for the points from the previous level up to be assigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No you do not** - the experience counter will still keep increasing although you will not be able to see the progress to the next level until you clear the "LVL UP!" banner by assigning the points.

[image]

This means it is perfectly possible to level up multiple times between assigning points.

Answer (score 0):

You will continue to gain exp. This can be seen by going to Menu -> Manage -> View Staff. You will also be able to assign points here, even in the middle of a batch. The increased skills will be considered for any as-yet uncontributed quality.